# Can I schedule YouTube videos for release via the API? And other 'limited' feature questions

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

There are several features on YouTube which channels earn access to by remaining in good standing for period of time, and by meeting other (unpublished) criteria. All of the following situations would require a user to be authenticated.

These features include:

- Ability to upload Custom Thumbnails
- Ability to schedule videos for release

These don't appear in online documentation anywhere nor can I find questions asking about them here on stack overflow. Are they supported by the API currently, or are there any plans to support them in the near future?

Additionally, Creators who are partners of the AdSense program have monetization settings for each video, including a status indicator of "in review", "monetized", "more information needed", etc. Creators who are partners with a MCN have other statuses such as "claimed" if they are a managed partner and (I believe) the same AdSense ones if they are an affiliate partner. (New system, still rolling out)

Is there a way to get the monetization status of a video and to change the monetization settings via the API? Once again, if this is not currently supported, is there any plans to support it in the future?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Setting custom thumbnails is via [thumbnails->set call](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/thumbnails/set).

code samples: [java](https://github.com/youtube/yt-samples-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/data/UploadThumbnail.java) [php](https://github.com/youtube/yt-samples-php/blob/master/upload_thumbnail.php) [python](https://github.com/youtube/yt-samples-python/blob/master/upload_thumbnail.py)

2) Scheduled videos are [requested in issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4293) and work in progress.

3) All monetization options are in Content ID API.

Comment: What is the current status on scheduled videos?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to schedule videos with the Youtube API v3.0.

When uploading via the *insert* method, videos can be scheduled by setting `status.privacyStatus` to `"private"`and setting `status.publishAt` to a string in the [ISO 8601 format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) specifying the date and time when the video will go public.

For example, if I wanted my video to be uploaded on November 1st, 2015 at 8:20 AM local time, my date/time string would look like `"2015-11-01T8:20:00.000+00:00"`

More information with code samples can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert).

Comment: this is exactly what I am doing, can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53873979/why-is-youtube-apis-schedule-video-not-working