# How to schedule a youtube video with youtube API V3 (c#)

Tags: c#, youtube, youtube-api

I recently created a youtube uploader for myself. I already have the code to upload as Unlisted, Public, or Private, but I do not know how to upload as a scheduled upload using C#.

`video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "unlisted"; // or "private" or "public"`

But how do i do this for Scheduled ?

Comment: Please show us the code

Comment: Added code to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `insert` method which is used for uploading a video to YouTube and optionally sets the video's metadata as given in [Videos](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos) and add the following properties in your request for a video resource :

- `status.publishAt: datetime`

  > The date and time when the video is scheduled to publish. **It can be set only if the privacy status of the video is private.** The value is specified in [ISO 8601](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) (YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sZ) format.
- `liveStreamingDetails.scheduledStartTime: datetime`

  > The time that the broadcast is scheduled to begin. The value is specified in ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sZ) format.
- `liveStreamingDetails.scheduledEndTime: datetime`

  > The time that the broadcast is scheduled to end. The value is specified in ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sZ) format. If the value is empty or the property is not present, then the broadcast is scheduled to continue indefinitely.

For more information and examples, you may also refer to [Videos: insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) and to this SO post - [Can I schedule YouTube videos for release via the API? And other 'limited' feature questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20025814/can-i-schedule-youtube-videos-for-release-via-the-api-and-other-limited-featu). I hope that helps. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks ! That is exactly what i needed !