# Why is Youtube API's schedule video not working?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using the exact example from here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert

To achieve scheduling this is what I have added to arguments:

```
privacyStatus='private', 
publishAt='2018-12-21T02:01:07.000Z'
```

(please verify `publishAt` has correct ISO 8601 format )

I am getting success(200) but the uploaded video is only private, not scheduled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, since I copied the code from example I forgot to update the `initialize_upload` function to include `publishAt` in the `status` dictionary.

```
def initialize_upload(youtube, options):
    tags = None
    if options.keywords:
        tags = options.keywords.split(',')

    body=dict(
        snippet=dict(
            title=options.title,
            description=options.description,
            tags=tags,
            categoryId=options.category
        ),
        status=dict(
            privacyStatus=options.privacyStatus,
            publishAt=options.publishAt
        )
    )
```